# Cookie to store post values

Tags: php

The link to the page contains values in the URL that I need to store so that they can be accessed when the user browses around the site.

I'm thinking a cookie is the best way to store these, then I can access the cookie when I need these values again. I see that cookies can only be created in the header before the HTML tags. is it possible for me to access the values in the URL in the header also, and put these inside the cookie?

Comment: I'm pretty sure cookies can be placed in the body section too.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can access the URL before you present HTML tags.  You can store these values either as cookies or using sessions.  The following link should help you find how to get the values you ant.

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php

EDIT: I got some karma, so I'll add the session documentation to my main answer.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

As @El Yobo mentions below, this is definitely the 'proper' way to do what you're trying to do.  Good luck!

Comment: There are some ridiculous rules in place for low karma users, so I'll also point out http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php which I would use ahead of cookies for what you've described.

Comment: +1 for the session suggestion; I would edit your original answer and put the session link instead of the other, to be honest, as the session approach is definitely what they should be doing.

Comment: Nothing should be stopping you from editing your own post to include that link. There is no rep requirement for editing your own posts.

Comment: @meagar - low rep users can't post more than one link is the problem, I suspect.

Comment: Yes, I wasn't more clear, but the problem was that I haven't answered any other questions and so I can only post one link in my response.  I wanted to link to the session documentation, the response documentation, and I believe the get documentation just to cover all my bases.  Either way, I think there's enough information here to get @Shwah going.